# Material UI, Appbar logo on left, Tabs in the center

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-grid

I make a react material ui AppBar.

There is a logo and tabs.
The tabs should be in the center of the AppBar and the logo on the left.
But I can't make the logo go to the left.

How can I make it to go the left?

I am using mui's Grid system but if there is better solution doesn't matter.

Here is a live example https://codesandbox.io/embed/delicate-feather-mmf3k

```
const Header = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <nav className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Toolbar style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
          <Grid justify={"center"} alignItems={"center"} container>
            <Grid style={{ justifySelf: "flex-start" }} item>
              <img
                className={classes.logo}
                src={
                  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/React-icon.svg"
                }
                alt="Logo"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Grid container justify={"center"}>
                <Tabs
                  onChange={(e, v) => setValue(v)}
                  value={value}
                  aria-label="Navigation Tabs"
                >
                  <Tab label={"page 1"} />
                  <Tab label={"page 2"} />
                </Tabs>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

In this case both the Logo and Tabs are in the center.

I tired to style `justifySelf`, `alignSelf` to `flex-start` on the logo to no avail.
Adding `xs` to the second Grid item, makes the logo to go to left but the Tabs are not exactly in the center in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution I came up with is to add empty 3rd Grid item.
Justify `'space-between'` on the Grid container.
Give `xs={1}` to the first Grid item, in which is the logo.
Give `xs={4}` to the tabs Grid item.
Give `xs={1}` to the third Grid item.

```
const Header = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <nav className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Toolbar>
          <Grid justify={"space-between"} container>
            <Grid xs={1} item>
              <img
                className={classes.logo}
                src={
                  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/React-icon.svg"
                }
                alt="Logo"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid xs={4} item>
              <Grid container justify={"center"}>
                <Tabs
                  onChange={(e, v) => setValue(v)}
                  value={value}
                  aria-label="Navigation Tabs"
                >
                  <Tab label={"page 1"} />
                  <Tab label={"page 2"} />
                </Tabs>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1} />
          </Grid>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-cloud-zwghk